# meaning of "I've been you"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

What does (I've been you) mean?
I was watching a movie in which a girl said :

*Do you still fancy me?*

The boy answered :
*Yes*

She said:
*You are lying. I've been you*

[Source](https://subslikescript.com/movie/Closer-376541) Closer (2004) - full transcript

Answer (score 2):

It probably means "I've been in your situation"  (and so I know you are lying, because I lied when I was in that situation).

Of course it doesn't literally mean "I've been in your situation".  The girl is speaking figuratively.

It isn't an idiom, nor is it particularly idiomatic.  I understand the meaning from context.